# Can't run UWP unit tests: Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm running into an issue in running unit tests in a Universal Windows Platform unit test library. Specifically, I'm getting the following error message:

> **Test adapter sent back a result for an unknown test case. Ignoring result for [unit test method name]**

Here are the things I've tried, but to no avail:

- Ensured the solution builds with the x86 platform; I've even tried x64 as the platform too, but the same error occurs.
- Ensured that the platform that the test runner is using matches the platform I build against (x86 or x64).
- Deleted the **bin** and **obj** folders.
- Restarted Visual Studio (numerous times).

Are there other things I can check for?

Edit: Some more environment-specific items that hopefully will shed more light on the issue:

- The unit test library project type I have is the Universal Windows Platform Unit Test library type.
- The tests do run successfully on my desktop, which is running VS2015 with Update 2 (Enterprise). However, on my laptop which is running the same version of VS, it runs into the above issue.

Comment: Did you create your project in Visual Studio 2015 RC and are trying to open that in Visual Studio 2015 RTM? If yes, please follow the step [Changes required for existing unit test projects for universal windows apps created with Visual Studio 2015 RC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501(v=vs.140).aspx#MigrateUnitTest).If not, you can submit a feedback [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback).

Comment: I created the solution with VS 2015 (Update 2 - Enterprise). Strangely, the unit tests run fine on my desktop (same VS version), but on my laptop it reports the error in question. I updated the question with some more environment info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue. It turns out I had at one point removed the following, critical attribute from the unit test project's `AssemblyInfo` file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("TargetPlatform", "UAP")]
```

Once I added it back in, the unit tests executed.

d'oh!